# Eclipse: The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find guava Predicate

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using new Eclipse Oxygen. My project setup includes Maven. One of the Maven dependencies is Guava:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

There are 2 problems I am facing that do not allow me to build the project:

1.
`The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for com.google.common.base.Predicate. Fix the build path then try building this project`

2.
`The type com.google.common.base.Predicate cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files [...] Java Problem`

Here is what I tried to solve it:
I have made clean & build of my project; I have closed and then reopened it; I have removed it from Eclipse and then re-imported and made clean & build.
Nothing seems to help.
Anyone has any ideas? This is super annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not related to Eclipse, but it was a maven issue.
In order to fix it I had to clear `~/.m2/repository` folder and run `Maven->Update Project` in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse by default uses embedded Maven. It is possible, that the guava dependency got corrupted in the embedded Maven's .m2 folder. Try to delete it from there.

Also try to change the Maven in Eclipse to use the same Maven as you use in the command line in:

```
  Preferences->Maven->Installations
```

Comment: I am using the same version

Comment: @IhorM. Try a Maven refresh (alt+F5) on your project. Can you see the class in the Open Type window (ctrl+shift+t and type "com.google.common.base.Predicate")? Check the Guava jar on the .m2 folder, open as a zip, and check the missing class, is it there, is it valid?